# Origin and purpose of Gandolfini's "Life is short" apparent life insurance ad that recently emerged?

Tags: comedy, the-sopranos

From Barstool Sports' [This Random James Gandolfini Commercial Is The Most Inspirational Thing You'll See Today](https://www.barstoolsports.com/blog/3349624/this-random-james-gandolfini-commercial-is-the-most-inspirational-thing-youll-see-today)

> HOW in God's name is this practically a never-before-seen video? That MafiaChronicles instagram account had never seen it, I've never seen it, and a bunch of people in the comments have never seen it. I truly need an explanation as to how I've been deprived of that until this very second. I could have EASILY wasted hours, maybe even days of my life, just rewatching that commercial & now I'll never get that lost time back. Either way- I'm ready to make up on the lost time because that video is nothing short of gold, Jerry. GOLD.

Below is a cluster of potential questions, **but there's no need to answer all of them separately of course** - I think a few basic facts about the clip are all that's needed to clear this all up.

What is the origin of this video - did Gandolfini organize and implement it himself, did someone else and just ask Gandolfini to be in it? Was its purpose pure humor or could it have actually been used to sell life insurance? Was it a short film shown on a late-night TV show?

Who produced it? Who paid for it? Who was its target audience exactly?

Comment: reason for drive-by down vote please?

Comment: Some people don't seem to like questions about movies and TV on this site.

Comment: @Valorum [smile](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/121369/45856)

Comment: Don't worry.  This is a good question and a perfectly acceptable one.  Valorum is absolutely correct in his comment ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a commercial for the HBO-owned TV station [*yes Oh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_Oh).

> The TV Advert titled James Gandolfini was done by McCann advertising agency for YES in Israel. It was released on July 2012.
>
> <sub><sup>https://www.advert.ge/en/commercials/yes/james_gandonfini.html</sup></sub>

You can see a version with the station ident at the end.

The same agency also created two other adverts for the same channel

Comment: Clearly I haven't watched enough HBO in my life, thanks for all the goodies!