# Did Mike Ehrmantraut ever laugh? Or even come close to it?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

Guessing that interacting with his niece Kaylee might be the only time he lets down his guard, I found a [Breaking Bad/Better Call Saul mashup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pl_WvC6Djyo) on YouTube where Ehrmantraut smiles seemingly to himself. He's also wearing a comparatively nice (and out of character) shirt, shown in screenshot below.

However, I wonder, and don't remember: *did Mike Ehrmantraut ever laugh?* If not, did he ever at least come close to it?

**note:** Laughter by the actor Jonathan Banks in out-takes or elsewhere doesn't count - it's got to be in character in an official released version of Breaking Bad or Better Call Saul.

---

[image: Mike Ehrmantraut (Jonathan Banks) smiling]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He laughs in *[BB: Half Measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_Measures)*, before his long monologue.

It's not a belly-laugh. More of a wry chuckle.

---

A similar chortle in *[BCS: Five-0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-O_(Better_Call_Saul))*

Again, not what you'd describe as a big laugh.